# Migrate classic Azure resources to new Azure resource manager

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

After switching to the new Azure portal, I see all resources of mine are listed as classic resources. I am googling around to see if it's possible to have classic VM and migrate it to ARM and just hadn't seen anything that stated it was possible.

I tried deleting the class VM but keep the VHD to check if I can attach it to the ARM VM. The result said it doesn't work.

Is there any way that can be used to achieve this ?

Comment: Given that a VHD is essentially a page blob, you can simply copy the blob to an ARM storage account and create a ARM VM using that. Have you tried going down this route?

Comment: Hi, David. I can copy the VHD within the classic storage but I couldn't figure out how to copy the blod to an ARM storage on the same account. I tried to Google around on the suggested route but there is not article on this topic. Can you give me more clue on this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately (and strangely!) there isn't a way to do this via the portal and you have to drop down to Powershell instead (or xplat / Rest)

When I have exported VMs from v1 to v2 I typically make the original vhd file accessible via a blob share (this can be done temporarily for the duration of this command)

You can then deploy a new VM using that vhd as a source image's URI, using

```
Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $vmname -VhdUri $uri -CreateOption FromImage -Windows
```

Alternatively you can copy the vhd to v2 storage and use `Attach` instead of `FromImage`

If you wrap that around a standard [VM Create script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603754.aspx), you should be good to go!

Comment: Hi, Michael. Thanks for your reply. I tried to copy my VHD from v1 to v2 storage but I couldn't figure it out. Do you have an external or reference link that I can refer to ?

Comment: @C.k. You need to use `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy` there are probably answers about it on here already, if you can't find them ask another question

Comment: @Micheal B, finally, I am able to copied one of my vhds to the Azure Rm storage account. The copied vhd size is 10GB. I am having issue to copy the Windows OS vhd, which is 127GB. The OS blob copied to Rm storage account is 0B. Any suggestion please?

Comment: I figured it out. I need to shut down/stop the v1 VM before I can copy the blob.

Comment: I tried to deployed a new VM with the command you suggested. The command can run w/o error. The issue I have is "OSProvisioningTimedOut". The provisioning of VM timed out before it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of powershell scripts to assist in migrating classic vms to the new resource group model -  [asm-arm](https://github.com/fullscale180/asm2arm)

They require the Azure and AzureRM powershell modules - [msdn link to installation instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/)